# Typeset math mode environments in scriptstyle

Tags: math-mode, environments, fontsize

I need to typeset `aligned` environment in script style.  Setting `\scriptsize` outside of the environment works, but the compiler complains:

```
Command \scriptsize invalid in math mode ...
```

Using `\scriptstyle` outside of the environment does not have any effect, and using it inside only has effect on the immediately following element of the content.

How can i typeset a math mode environment, like `aligned`, using `scriptstyle` correctly?

---

Here is an example that i would like to fix (avoid `\scriptsize`):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&2&2\\
    1&2&-1\\
    -1&1&4
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    0&1&0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \underset{\scriptsize
    \begin{aligned}
      L_2&\leftarrow L_2 - L_1\\
      L_3&\leftarrow L_3 + L_1
    \end{aligned}}{\Leftrightarrow}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&2&2\\
    0&0&-3\\
    0&3&6
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    -1&1&0\\
    1&0&1
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \underset{\scriptsize
    \begin{aligned}
      L_3&\leftarrow L_3 + 2L_2
    \end{aligned}}{\Leftrightarrow}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&2&2\\
    0&0&-3\\
    0&3&0
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    -1&1&0\\
    -1&2&1
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \underset{\scriptsize
    \begin{aligned}
      L_2&\leftarrow (-1/3)L_2\\
      L_3&\leftarrow (1/3)L_3
    \end{aligned}}{\Leftrightarrow}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&2&2\\
    0&0&1\\
    0&1&0
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    1/3&-1/3&0\\
    -1/3&2/3&1/3
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \underset{\scriptsize
    \begin{aligned}
      L_1&\leftarrow L_1 - 2L_2 - 2L_3
    \end{aligned}}{\Leftrightarrow}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    0&0&1\\
    0&1&0
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&-2/3&-2/3\\
    1/3&-1/3&0\\
    -1/3&2/3&1/3
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \underset{\scriptsize
    \begin{aligned}
      L_2&\leftrightarrow L_3
    \end{aligned}}{\Leftrightarrow}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    0&1&0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&-2/3&-2/3\\
    -1/3&2/3&1/3\\
    1/3&-1/3&0
  \end{pmatrix*}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? May be `\substack` or `\subarray` would fit you?

Comment: I tried `\substack` with `aligned` inside, it didn't help.  I would like to have `aligned`, not just `subarray`.  Some aligned material under "$\Leftrightarrow$".

Comment: we really need an actual example.  setting display math in a size different from the main text is fraught with unpleasant side effects.  they can be dealt with, but the circumstances need to be known with some certainty.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: As I suspected, you just need `subarray`.

Comment: I do not think so, i want the lines to be aligned on the arrows, even if visually it does not make big difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{scriptaligned}[1][c]
 {\,\hbox\bgroup
  \fontsize{\sf@size}{\dimexpr\sf@size pt+1pt}\selectfont
  $\!\aligned[#1]}
 {\endaligned$\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x\begin{scriptaligned}a&=b\\c&=d\end{scriptaligned}$\qquad
$x\begin{scriptaligned}[t]a&=b\\c&=d\end{scriptaligned}$\qquad
$x\begin{scriptaligned}[b]a&=b\\c&=d\end{scriptaligned}$

\LARGE
$x\begin{scriptaligned}a&=b\\c&=d\end{scriptaligned}$\qquad
$x\begin{scriptaligned}[t]a&=b\\c&=d\end{scriptaligned}$\qquad
$x\begin{scriptaligned}[b]a&=b\\c&=d\end{scriptaligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, for the simple application you have in mind, `subarray` is sufficient and simpler.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\rowop}[1]{%
  \underset{\begin{subarray}{l}#1\end{subarray}}{\Leftrightarrow}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&2&2\\
    1&2&-1\\
    -1&1&4
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    0&1&0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \rowop{L_2\leftarrow L_2 - L_1 \\ L_3\leftarrow L_3 + L_1}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&2&2\\
    0&0&-3\\
    0&3&6
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    -1&1&0\\
    1&0&1
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \rowop{L_3\leftarrow L_3 + 2L_2}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&2&2\\
    0&0&-3\\
    0&3&0
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    -1&1&0\\
    -1&2&1
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \rowop{L_2\leftarrow (-1/3)L_2 \\ L_3\leftarrow (1/3)L_3}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&2&2\\
    0&0&1\\
    0&1&0
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    1/3&-1/3&0\\
    -1/3&2/3&1/3
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \rowop{L_1\leftarrow L_1 - 2L_2 - 2L_3}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    0&0&1\\
    0&1&0
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&-2/3&-2/3\\
    1/3&-1/3&0\\
    -1/3&2/3&1/3
  \end{pmatrix*}\\
  \rowop{L_2\leftrightarrow L_3}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&0&0\\
    0&1&0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{pmatrix*}X
  =\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    1&-2/3&-2/3\\
    -1/3&2/3&1/3\\
    1/3&-1/3&0
  \end{pmatrix*}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but is there no easier way?  Defining a new environment would be fine, but not from scratch.  I am afraid i will prefer compiler complain about `\scriptsize`.

Comment: @Alexey I put on line a simpler version. The problem is that doing `\scriptsize` will not work if the current font size is different from `\normalsize` (say in a footnote), so using `\sf@size` is the way to go.

Comment: Maybe you don't really need `aligned`, but `\subarray` or a version thereof. Can you add some examples of what you need?

Comment: What exactly does `\,`?

Comment: @Manuel `aligned` has it, so I wanted to reproduce it.

Comment: @egreg -- it's not at all clear to me whether use of `aligned` implies a display or not; if it does, there are other things that need to be considered.  if it's just a small thing, why not just bury it in `\text{\scriptsize ...}`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton It would work just at `\normalsize`

Comment: @egreg -- yup.  you're correct.